# Wordpress: Ninja Forms pass form data to popup form

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ninja-forms

I have a Ninja Forms form which asks for the email address and a optin checkbox. After the user submits, it opens a popup with a follow up form (using plugin Popup Maker) where the user is asked to enter more (optional) details. As the follow up form has its own submissions table, I would like to pass the email address of the first form to the popup follow-up form, so that the user doesn't have to enter it again.
Ideally, it saves all this info into just one submissions table, but I guess Ninja Forms isn't constructed that way (?).

Using the Submission Processing Hooks (http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/submission-processing-hooks/), I added the following code to the theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'ninja_forms_after_submission', 'ninja_forms_save_email_to_cookie' );

function ninja_forms_save_email_to_cookie( $form_data ){
    $cookie_name = "nl_email";
    $cookie_value = $form_data;
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value); // Session cookie.
}
```

But no cookie is saved.

For the follow-up form I have this in the theme's `functions.php` which is supposed to fill a hidden form field (field key is `email_1519816442526`) with the cookie's value before doing any other processing of the follow up form:

```
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_submit_data', 'ninja_forms_submit_followup' );

function ninja_forms_submit_followup( $form_data ) {
    $cookie_name = "nl_email";
    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) && $form_data['id'] == 2) {
        $form_data['fields']['email_1519816442526']['value'] = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]; // Update the submitted field value.
    }

    return $form_data;
}
```

Are the Submission Hooks the right point to integrate this feature? Or is this better done through a Custom Action? Are Custom Actions defined in the `functions.php` or someplace else? I couldn't find information on this in the Ninja Forms docs.

Comment: If both forms pop up one after the other without the browser leaving the site, you should be able to grab the 1st form's email and put it in the 2nd form using JavaScript. We'd have to install Wordpress and both plugins to tell you how to do this, i.e. basically do your work for you, so I'll leave it at that for now.

Comment: Alright, I edited my question. I'm not asking for the work to be done by anyone. I would just like to know if I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see the NinjaDev Docs where they provided the way we can change the value of a field using JS. We need to pass the value and trigger the change event.

See the [Explanation Here](https://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/changing-field-values/)

I needed this too so I researched and achieved this. I know I am late but if someone benefits from this then it's worth sharing here.

Working code below:

```
<!-- HTML Code Starts -->

<form class="short-form" method='post'>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Enter email" value="" id="shortEmail">
  <input type="button" class="popup-class-name" name="Proceed" value="Proceed" onclick="passValue();">
</form>

<!-- HTML Code Ends -->
```

```
<!-- JS Script Starts -->

function passValue() {
    var shortFormEmail, longFormEmail;
    var fieldID = 11;     // Target ID of the long form Email field
    shortFormEmail = document.getElementById('shortEmail');
    longFormEmail = shortFormEmail.value;
    jQuery('#nf-field-' + fieldID).val(longFormEmail).trigger('change'); //from ninja Dev
         // This will not work on any online IDE. Try it in actual ninja forms environment
  }

<!-- JS Script Ends -->
```

This will only work in Ninja Forms environment.